# Why a backslash displays as "W"+strikethrough in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I'm facing a strange problem with Netbeans.
In the editor, when I type a backslash(), I see a W with a strikethrough (as shown in the attached image).

So the `c:\\abc` is displaying as:

[image: Backslash displays as W-with-strikethrough in Netbeans]

But, when I copy and paste that string into notepad, it gets pasted normally (i.e. `c:\\abc`).

Has anyone faced this problem before? How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a currency symbol for [won](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%82%A9).

Check your editor's font settings, in particular the "Script" field (if there is one).

---

Michael Kaplan's post [**When is a backslash not a backslash?**](http://www.siao2.com/2005/09/17/469941.aspx) says:

> The character in question is U+005c, the REVERSE SOLIDUS, also known as the backslash or '\'. It is the path separator for Windows, **which is encoded at 0x5c across all of the ANSI code pages.**
>
> Since path separators are a pretty important requirement, the title of this post may seem a little scary -- how could it not be a backslash, a reverse solidus?
>
> Well, on Japanese code page 932, 0x5c is the YEN SIGN, and **on Korean code page 949, 0x5c is the WON SIGN.**
>
> Which is not to say that 0x5c does not act as a path separator -- it still does. And which is also not to say that the Unicode code points for the Yen and the Won (U+00a5 and U+20a9) do act as path separators -- because they do not.

Comment: lool! My font was set to `Malgun Gothic`. Thanks!

Comment: so it is not possible to get a backslash in that font. what should one do to have backslash in such fonts. I am using GungshuChe in the terminal for coding and I need backslash

Answer (score 0):

It is the font that is displayed on the screen.

for an example, if you "malgun gothic" and type "\", you will see the "W" with the strike through